# How to redirect a process(pid)'s traffic via a socks5 (or any) proxy?

Tags: proxy, socks5-proxy

Say if I have a process that I want to redirect all the traffic to a proxy while not effecting other processes (let's say if I run multiple node applications and I only want one of them to go through a proxy). Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't started this process yet, or can restart it, you can use `socksify` to make its network I/O go through a SOCKS server.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/socksify